# How to parse Java properties which contains variables?

Tags: java, properties

I'm loading a file of Java properties which looks like:

```
transfer_detail = Transfer {0} from {1} to {2} on {3}
```

After parsing that property I should have String that looks like:

```
Transfer 200.30 from Debit Account to Credit Account on 2011/01/26
```

I implemented my self a parser which looks like:

```
// simplified for brevity
private static String translate(String string, String... replacements){
    String result = string;
    for(int i = 0; i < replacements.length; i++){
        result = result.replace("{"+i+"}", replacements[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
// and I use it this way:
String result = translate("transaction", "200.30", "Debit Account", etc...);
```

What I've been wondering is if there's something to do so in the J2SE API. Even for simple things like this I don't like to reinvent the wheel. Do you know any other easier or cleaner way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use [the `MessageFormat` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) for filling in the placeholders with actual values.

Answer (score 5):

Don't do that... it's yucky. :)

Use [MessageFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) instead.

```
MessageFormat form = new MessageFormat("Transfer {0} from {1} to {2} on {3}");

System.out.println(form.format(new String[] {
        "200.30",
        "Debit Account",
        "Credit Account",
        "2011/01/26"
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

API MessageFormat doesn't work with messages containing quotes.

You have to manually do the job by using regex for example.