# Inserting named property values, a la Ant

Tags: java, parsing

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805444/how-to-parse-java-properties-which-contains-variables), which asks how to substitute properties into a string such as

> Transfer {0} from {1} to {2} on {3}

The answer to that question, the `MessageFormat` class, won't work with my needs.  I'd like to substitute named parameteres into a string like:

> The {weather} in {location} stays mainly in the {terrain}.

or perhaps

> The ${weather} in ${location} stays mainly in the ${terrain}.

Am I lucky enough that there already exists a class like `MessageFormat` to help with that or should I cobble together something on my own to do it?  Ant does this with build.xml - but short of lifting their code I'm wondering if there is already an existing class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest creating a new class called `CustomMessageFormat`:

```
public class CustomMessageFormat
{
    public static String format( String message, Object[] params )
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "\\{(.*?)\\}" );
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( message );
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        int i = 0;
        while ( matcher.find() )
        {
            matcher.appendReplacement( sb, "{" + ( i++ ) + "}" );
        }
        matcher.appendTail( sb );

        return MessageFormat.format( sb.toString(), params );
    }
}
```

That all that does is replace all your {sometext} tokens with sequential ones ({1}, {2} etc.) as required by `MessageFormat.format` method.

The you can simply use:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    String inputMessage = "The {def1} in {def2} stays mainly in the {def3}.";
    String result = CustomMessageFormat.format( inputMessage, new Object[] { "sun", "Paris", "suburbs" } );
    System.out.println( result );
}
```

This is, of course, a rough example, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks.  This is close to what I need. The idea behind the named params is I have a mapping of named param -> value. Using `Object[]` means I need to know the order the named params appear (if they appear at all), and the array has to be in that order as well.  If I could satisfy those requirements I could use {0}, {1}, etc.  You gave me a good start though.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a template engine for such a thing. Java has [many](http://www.google.com/search?q=template+engine+java) of them. Two popular ones are:

- [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net)
- [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)

A demo using StringTemplate:

```
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate;

public class STDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringTemplate st = new StringTemplate(
        "The $weather$ in $location$ stays mainly in the $terrain$."
    );
    st.setAttribute("weather", "rain");
    st.setAttribute("location", "London");
    st.setAttribute("terrain", "pubs");
    System.out.println(st.toString());
  }
}
```

would print:

```
The rain in London stays mainly in the pubs.
```

Comment: do you know of any lighter weight solutions? In the past I've re-written this clean-room style at every organization I've worked at...

Comment: @Dilum, undoubtedly there are more lightweight solutions, but these are the one ones I've ever tried.